# Indexing a field for both phrase searching and partial matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating an index on an object, and wanting to be able to do both full phrase searches as well as partial matches.  The type is called "deponent", and a simplified index creation is shown below:

```
{
   "deponent": {
      "properties": {         
         "name": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "full": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "omit_norms": true,
                  "index_options": "docs",
                  "include_in_all": false
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The intent of this is to index the values in the "name" field twice: once where the individual words within the field are not broken up (name.full) and once where the words are broken up (name.name).

I have a document which has been indexed whose name field is set to "Dr. Danny Watson".  I would expect the following behaviors to occur when executing a term query (whose query string is not analyzed according to the documentation):

1. When searching **name.full** using "Dr. Danny Watson", the record
   **should be** returned
2. When searching **name.full** using "Watson", the record **should not be** returned
3. When searching **name.name** using "Dr. Danny Watson", the record **should not be** returned
4. When searching **name.name** using "Watson", the record **should be** returned

The queries for the four points above:

1 - works as expected (returns the record)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
           "name.full": {
              "value": "Dr. Danny Watson"
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

2 - works as expected (does not return the record)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
           "name.full": {
              "value": "Watson"
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

3 - works as expected (does not return the record)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
           "name.name": {
              "value": "Dr. Danny Watson"
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

4 -  does **NOT** work as expected - the record is not returned

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
           "name.name": {
              "value": "Watson"
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

So it seems my understanding of something is flawed.  What am I missing?

Comment: What analyzers are you using? Can it be that your index and search analyzers are different? Try looking for "watson" on your name.name field (that is all in lower case). Does that bring results?

Comment: The above are the complete index creation and search requests.  So other than specified, the defaults are being used.  Changing the search query text to lowercase doesn't change anything.

Comment: ah, and you don't need to call the field "name.name". The multi-field with the original name is used as the default, so you should use just "name" for that.

Comment: I swear I did it that way originally and it didn't work.  It's possible that I didn't delete my mapping first and so the mapping wasn't actually changed.  Changing name.name to just name in the query works now; if you post an answer based on the columns I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the field "name.name". The multi-field with the original name is used as the default, so you should use just "name" for that.
Also it's always good to make sure the index and search analyzers are in order (so for instance both your indexed terms and the search term are changed to lower case).