# How do I give whole words priority in elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is running well for me at the moment, however I want to give whole words priority over Ngrams.

I've tried the following:

```
client.indices.create index: index,
                      body: {
                          mappings: {
                              search_variable: {
                                  properties: {
                                      "name" => {
                                          "type" => "string",
                                          "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                      },
                                      "label" => {
                                          "type" => "string",
                                          "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                      },
                                      "value_labels" => {
                                          "type" => "string",
                                          "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                      },
                                      "value_label_search_string" => {
                                          "type" => "string",
                                          "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                      },
                                      "search_text" => {
                                          "type" => "multi_field",
                                          "fields" => {
                                            "whole_words" => {"type" => "string", "analyzer" => "simple"},
                                            "ngram" => {"type" => "string", "analyzer" => "ngram", "search_analyzer" => "ngram_search"}
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              },
                              settings: {
                                  analysis: {
                                      filter: {
                                          ngram: {
                                              type: 'nGram',
                                              min_gram: 3,
                                              max_gram: 25
                                          }
                                      },
                                      analyzer: {
                                          ngram: {
                                              tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                                              filter: ['lowercase', 'stop', 'ngram'],
                                              type: 'custom'
                                          },
                                          ngram_search: {
                                              tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                                              filter: ['lowercase', 'stop'],
                                              type: 'custom'
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }   
                      }
```

This is the part relevant to my full text search field: `search_text`:

```
"search_text" => {
    "type" => "multi_field",
    "fields" => {
        "whole_words" => {"type" => "string", "analyzer" => "simple"},
        "ngram" => {"type" => "string", "analyzer" => "ngram", "search_analyzer" => "ngram_search"}
    }
}
```

I want to give higher scores to items that match whole words in the search text.

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [ngram_search] not found for field [ngram]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [search_variable]: analyzer [ngram_search] not found for field [ngram]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [ngram_search] not found for field [ngram]"}},"status":400}
```

Here's the error:
`"reason":"analyzer [ngram_search] not found for field [ngram]"`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here is my query, where I tried to match on whole words only for now, and I only get 0 results every time.

```
    search_query = {
        index: index,
        body: {
            _source: {
                exclude: ["search_text", "survey_id"]
            },
            query: {
                :bool => {
                    :filter => {
                        :term => {"survey_id" => 12}
                    },
                    :must => {
                        :match => {
                          "search_text.whole_words" => {"query" => "BMW", "operator" => "and"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result = client.search(search_query)
```

Here is the output of:
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/yg_search_variables`

```
{"yg_search_variables":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"search_variable":{"properties":{"label":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"search_text":{"type":"string","index":"no","fields":{"ngram":{"type":"string","analyzer":"ngram","search_analyzer":"ngram_search"},"whole_words":{"type":"string","analyzer":"simple"}}},"value_label_search_string":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"value_labels":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"variables":{"properties":{"category":{"type":"string"},"label":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"search_text":{"type":"string","index":"no"},"survey_id":{"type":"long"},"value_label_search_text":{"type":"string"},"value_labels":{"properties":{"0":{"type":"string"},"1":{"type":"string"},"10":{"type":"string"},"100":{"type":"string"},"101":{"type":"string"},"102":{"type":"string"},"103":{"type":"string"},"104":{"type":"string"},"105":{"type":"string"},"106":{"type":"string"},"107":{"type":"string"},"108":{"type":"string"},"109":{"type":"string"},"11":{"type":"string"},"110":{"type":"string"},"1100":{"type":"string"},"1101":{"type":"string"},"1102":{"type":"string"},"1103":{"type":"string"},"1104":{"type":"string"},"1105":{"type":"string"},"1106":{"type":"string"},"1107":{"type":"string"},"1108":{"type":"string"},"1109":{"type":"string"},"111":{"type":"string"},"1110":{"type":"string"},"1111":{"type":"string"},"1112":{"type":"string"},"1113":{"type":"string"},"1114":{"type":"string"},"112":{"type":"string"},"113":{"type":"string"},"114":{"type":"string"},"115":{"type":"string"},"116":{"type":"string"},"117":{"type":"string"},"118":{"type":"string"},"119":{"type":"string"},"12":{"type":"string"},"120":{"type":"string"},"121":{"type":"string"},"122":{"type":"string"},"123":{"type":"string"},"124":{"type":"string"},"125":{"type":"string"},"126":{"type":"string"},"127":{"type":"string"},"128":{"type":"string"},"129":{"type":"string"},"13":{"type":"string"},"130":{"type":"string"},"131":{"type":"string"},"132":{"type":"string"},"133":{"type":"string"},"134":{"type":"string"},"135":{"type":"string"},"136":{"type":"string"},"137":{"type":"string"},"138":{"type":"string"},"139":{"type":"string"},"14":{"type":"string"},"140":{"type":"string"},"141":{"type":"string"},"142":{"type":"string"},"143":{"type":"string"},"144":{"type":"string"},"145":{"type":"string"},"146":{"type":"string"},"147":{"type":"string"},"148":{"type":"string"},"149":{"type":"string"},"15":{"type":"string"},"150":{"type":"string"},"151":{"type":"string"},"152":{"type":"string"},"153":{"type":"string"},"154":{"type":"string"},"155":{"type":"string"},"156":{"type":"string"},"157":{"type":"string"},"158":{"type":"string"},"159":{"type":"string"},"16":{"type":"string"},"160":{"type":"string"},"161":{"type":"string"},"162":{"type":"string"},"163":{"type":"string"},"164":{"type":"string"},"165":{"type":"string"},"166":{"type":"string"},"167":{"type":"string"},"168":{"type":"string"},"169":{"type":"string"},"17":{"type":"string"},"170":{"type":"string"},"171":{"type":"string"},"172":{"type":"string"},"173":{"type":"string"},"174":{"type":"string"},"175":{"type":"string"},"176":{"type":"string"},"177":{"type":"string"},"178":{"type":"string"},"179":{"type":"string"},"18":{"type":"string"},"180":{"type":"string"},"181":{"type":"string"},"182":{"type":"string"},"183":{"type":"string"},"184":{"type":"string"},"185":{"type":"string"},"186":{"type":"string"},"187":{"type":"string"},"188":{"type":"string"},"189":{"type":"string"},"19":{"type":"string"},"190":{"type":"string"},"191":{"type":"string"},"192":{"type":"string"},"193":{"type":"string"},"194":{"type":"string"},"195":{"type":"string"},"196":{"type":"string"},"197":{"type":"string"},"198":{"type":"string"},"199":{"type":"string"},"2":{"type":"string"},"20":{"type":"string"},"200":{"type":"string"},"201":{"type":"string"},"202":{"type":"string"},"203":{"type":"string"},"204":{"type":"string"},"205":{"type":"string"},"206":{"type":"string"},"207":{"type":"string"},"208":{"type":"string"},"209":{"type":"string"},"21":{"type":"string"},"210":{"type":"string"},"211":{"type":"string"},"22":{"type":"string"},"23":{"type":"string"},"24":{"type":"string"},"25":{"type":"string"},"26":{"type":"string"},"27":{"type":"string"},"28":{"type":"string"},"29":{"type":"string"},"3":{"type":"string"},"30":{"type":"string"},"301":{"type":"string"},"302":{"type":"string"},"303":{"type":"string"},"304":{"type":"string"},"305":{"type":"string"},"306":{"type":"string"},"307":{"type":"string"},"308":{"type":"string"},"309":{"type":"string"},"31":{"type":"string"},"310":{"type":"string"},"311":{"type":"string"},"312":{"type":"string"},"313":{"type":"string"},"314":{"type":"string"},"315":{"type":"string"},"316":{"type":"string"},"317":{"type":"string"},"32":{"type":"string"},"33":{"type":"string"},"34":{"type":"string"},"35":{"type":"string"},"36":{"type":"string"},"37":{"type":"string"},"38":{"type":"string"},"39":{"type":"string"},"4":{"type":"string"},"40":{"type":"string"},"41":{"type":"string"},"42":{"type":"string"},"43":{"type":"string"},"44":{"type":"string"},"45":{"type":"string"},"46":{"type":"string"},"47":{"type":"string"},"48":{"type":"string"},"49":{"type":"string"},"5":{"type":"string"},"50":{"type":"string"},"51":{"type":"string"},"52":{"type":"string"},"53":{"type":"string"},"54":{"type":"string"},"55":{"type":"string"},"554":{"type":"string"},"555":{"type":"string"},"556":{"type":"string"},"56":{"type":"string"},"57":{"type":"string"},"58":{"type":"string"},"59":{"type":"string"},"6":{"type":"string"},"60":{"type":"string"},"601":{"type":"string"},"602":{"type":"string"},"603":{"type":"string"},"604":{"type":"string"},"61":{"type":"string"},"62":{"type":"string"},"63":{"type":"string"},"64":{"type":"string"},"65":{"type":"string"},"66":{"type":"string"},"666":{"type":"string"},"667":{"type":"string"},"67":{"type":"string"},"68":{"type":"string"},"69":{"type":"string"},"7":{"type":"string"},"70":{"type":"string"},"71":{"type":"string"},"72":{"type":"string"},"73":{"type":"string"},"74":{"type":"string"},"75":{"type":"string"},"76":{"type":"string"},"77":{"type":"string"},"777":{"type":"string"},"78":{"type":"string"},"79":{"type":"string"},"8":{"type":"string"},"80":{"type":"string"},"801":{"type":"string"},"802":{"type":"string"},"803":{"type":"string"},"804":{"type":"string"},"805":{"type":"string"},"806":{"type":"string"},"807":{"type":"string"},"808":{"type":"string"},"809":{"type":"string"},"81":{"type":"string"},"810":{"type":"string"},"811":{"type":"string"},"812":{"type":"string"},"813":{"type":"string"},"814":{"type":"string"},"815":{"type":"string"},"816":{"type":"string"},"817":{"type":"string"},"818":{"type":"string"},"819":{"type":"string"},"82":{"type":"string"},"820":{"type":"string"},"821":{"type":"string"},"822":{"type":"string"},"83":{"type":"string"},"84":{"type":"string"},"85":{"type":"string"},"86":{"type":"string"},"87":{"type":"string"},"88":{"type":"string"},"888":{"type":"string"},"89":{"type":"string"},"9":{"type":"string"},"90":{"type":"string"},"901":{"type":"string"},"902":{"type":"string"},"903":{"type":"string"},"904":{"type":"string"},"905":{"type":"string"},"906":{"type":"string"},"907":{"type":"string"},"908":{"type":"string"},"909":{"type":"string"},"91":{"type":"string"},"910":{"type":"string"},"911":{"type":"string"},"912":{"type":"string"},"913":{"type":"string"},"914":{"type":"string"},"915":{"type":"string"},"916":{"type":"string"},"917":{"type":"string"},"918":{"type":"string"},"919":{"type":"string"},"92":{"type":"string"},"920":{"type":"string"},"921":{"type":"string"},"922":{"type":"string"},"923":{"type":"string"},"924":{"type":"string"},"925":{"type":"string"},"926":{"type":"string"},"927":{"type":"string"},"928":{"type":"string"},"93":{"type":"string"},"94":{"type":"string"},"95":{"type":"string"},"96":{"type":"string"},"97":{"type":"string"},"98":{"type":"string"},"99":{"type":"string"},"997":{"type":"string"},"998":{"type":"string"},"999":{"type":"string"}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1457103857764","analysis":{"filter":{"ngram":{"type":"nGram","min_gram":"3","max_gram":"25"}},"analyzer":{"ngram":{"filter":["lowercase","stop","ngram"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"whitespace"},"ngram_search":{"filter":["lowercase","stop"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"whitespace"}}},"number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"zPN2LDfCTFqPleW7d5nkwA","version":{"created":"2020099"}}},"warmers":{}}}%
```

It seems strange that index is `no`:

```
     "search_text": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "no",
        "fields": {
          "ngram": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "ngram",
            "search_analyzer": "ngram_search"
          },
          "whole_words": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "simple"
          }
        }
      }
```

Edit: Here is a sample matching document for the term "Ford":

```
{
  "name"=>"car_ownership", 
  "label"=>"Customer: Ford", 
  "category"=>["Vehicles", "Passenger Vehicles"], "value"=>nil, 
  "value_labels"=>{"1"=>"Yes", "2"=>"No"}, 
  "node_id"=>14813, 
  "survey_id" => 12,
  "search_text" => "Customer Ford Vehicles Passenger Vehicles Yes No"
}
```

Edit: I have added a smaller beginning to end test case that can be found here, which replicates the error.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwxm3qe0oxc2z5y/Slimmed%20ElasticSearch%20Text%20%281%29.html?dl=0

Comment: You need to move `settings` up one level, i.e. it must not be contained in the `mappings` section. That will get rid of the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right.

Comment: Let me test and get back to you.

Comment: Though it doesn't mean your query will work, but just that your index will be created with the correct settings, which is a pre-requisite for then working on those analyzers

Comment: I posted my query, because before my Ngrams were working fine, but now I'm getting 0 hits for everything.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get from  `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: @Val do you have any further comment here?

Comment: Do you mind showing one document that should match the query you're using? (i.e. with `survey_id: 12` and `search_text: BMW`)

Comment: @Val added to question, my question is similar to this, except in my case by sub-field just doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496850/indexing-a-field-for-both-phrase-searching-and-partial-matches

Comment: I added it, I think it might be wise to close this question and start a new one given that I am no longer experiencing the error, just 0 results.

Comment: Weird, you must have another issue, because I could recreate the index with the same settings, index the Ford document and your query yields one result. Maybe, you can wipe it all out and rebuild from scratch clean, and try again.

Comment: That does seem very strange, do you have the complete code that did that, I have been deleting the index and re-creating each time to no avail, and I'm loading using the bulk API.

Comment: Can you show one bulk command you're sending?

Comment: @Val I've added the dropbox link to a smaller test case that I prepared.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that `settings` is not properly nested when you create your index. `settings` and `mappings` should be at the same level.

Then, looking at your dropbox file, I think the issue is that the mapping type is called `search_variable` while in your bulk you are using the mapping type `test_type`. Hence the mapping will never be applied.

Comment: Works like a charm! The only problem I have now is setting the value label field to `not_analyzed`, because that field is a hash and throws an error. Thank you.

Comment: Cool it worked out. Let's see that new problem in a new question.