# Analyzing the same search field twice returns 0 results on subfield in ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I have a field called `search_text` which is a full text search field.

I am using ngrams to index this field, I wanted to add a new sub-field `search_text.words` that will index this on whole words.

**I tried to implement this, but querying the `search_text.words` always returns 0 hits.**

I am creating it like this:

```
  "search_text" => {
      "type" => "string",
      "analyzer" => "ngram",
      "search_analyzer" => "ngram_search",
      "fields" => {
          "words" => {"type" => "string",
                      "analyzer" => "ngram_search"}
      }
  }
```

I have a full demonstration here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwxm3qe0oxc2z5y/Slimmed%20ElasticSearch%20Text%20%281%29.html?dl=0

Comment: Very similar to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798886/how-do-i-give-whole-words-priority-in-elasticsearch, which I still have to answer :)

Comment: It is, I tried to rephrase it, because the other question technically was answered with the error of placing the settings in the wrong place. Thanks for your help so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your dropbox file, I think the issue is that the mapping type is called `search_variable` while in your bulk query you are using the mapping type `test_type`.

Hence the mapping will never be applied.

If you change your bulk query to this, it will work

```
bulk_insert_items = items_to_insert.flat_map do |item|
      [
        {index: {_index: 'test_index', _type: 'search_variable'}},
        item
      ]
end
```